# SignalR fails to start connection in aspnetcore 2.1

Tags: connection, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

Am trying to follow this tutorial https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview1-getting-started-with-signalr/ for SignalR. Have installed the proper version of signaR 2.1 as well as Visual Studio Preview. My program seems to compile OK, but when I load the Chat page, the Start connection fails.Am using Chrome.

The console log shows the following error:

```
Information: Normalizing '/hubs/chat' to 'https://localhost:44380/hubs/chat'
signalr.js:1337 

POST https://localhost:44380/hubs/chat/negotiate 500 ()
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:1337
DefaultHttpClient.send @ signalr.js:1302
HttpClient.post @ signalr.js:1291
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:1870
step @ signalr.js:1816
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:1797
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:1791
__awaiter @ signalr.js:1787
HttpConnection.startInternal @ signalr.js:1851
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:1845
step @ signalr.js:1816
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:1797
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:1791
__awaiter @ signalr.js:1787
HttpConnection.start @ signalr.js:1839
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:2347
step @ signalr.js:2232
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:2213
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:2207
__awaiter @ signalr.js:2203
HubConnection.start @ signalr.js:2338
(anonymous) @ chat:44
signalr.js:1744 

Error: Failed to start the connection. Error
ConsoleLogger.log @ signalr.js:1744
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:1903
step @ signalr.js:1816
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:1797
rejected @ signalr.js:1789
Promise.then (async)
step @ signalr.js:1790
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:1791
__awaiter @ signalr.js:1787
HttpConnection.startInternal @ signalr.js:1851
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:1845
step @ signalr.js:1816
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:1797
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:1791
__awaiter @ signalr.js:1787
HttpConnection.start @ signalr.js:1839
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:2347
step @ signalr.js:2232
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:2213
(anonymous) @ signalr.js:2207
__awaiter @ signalr.js:2203
HubConnection.start @ signalr.js:2338
(anonymous) @ chat:44
signalr.js:1231 

Uncaught (in promise) Error
    at new HttpError (signalr.js:1231)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (signalr.js:1328)
```

Comment: Post what you tried so far.

Comment: Tried debugging but it fails in the signalR.js file and am new to this tech. Am going to try to implement a diff approach of SignaR using the Controller rather than a new Model, following this guide here: [link](https://radu-matei.com/blog/signalr-core/) as all I want is to have a controller method in c# calling a javascript method from the index from time to time whilst the algorithm is in progress.